# Really minor typo in HTML source

Tags: bug, status-completed

Every instance of `class="question-hyperlink"` has an extra `"` after it, causing errors to show up in the browser console.

Like I said in the title, really minor. Sue me for being a perfectionist :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra `"` was showing when rendering question titles on the question page and in the related sidebar (possibly other locations as well).

This has been fixed and will appear in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

While we're at it, W3C gives a warning when validating as valid HTML5:

> No Character encoding declared at document level
>
> No character encoding information was found within the document, either in an HTML meta element or an XML declaration. It is often recommended to declare the character encoding in the document itself, especially if there is a chance that the document will be read from or saved to disk, **CD**, etc. *<-- Who runs webpages from CDs..?*

Nitpicking is fine, the minor errors are the most fun!

Comment: Well, the character encoding is specified in the HTTP `Content-Type` header (`text/html; charset=utf-8`) so this warning is averted.

Comment: Yeah, it's still valid HTML5, just thought it could be nice to point out :) Just in case anybody wanted to save something to a CD... Hah!

Comment: Most of the software and games I've used from a CD comes with HTML-formatted help files, although admittedly the last time I installed software from a CD was about 8 years ago XD

Comment: Exactly! :)  . .